# Any way to hide elements from webview? (android)

Tags: android, webview

There's a webpage I pull up with webview, however i'd like to hide the 1 text link at the top. Is there a way to do this? The link is in the body, so I can't hide the body element in whole.
The webpage is all text, and one tiny image at the bottom, but the text is generated each time you load it, so I can't just copy/paste the body.

Thanks

Answer (score 26):

```
final WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.browser);

    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
     @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
    {
        // hide element by class name
        webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                "document.getElementsByClassName('your_class_name')[0].style.display='none'; })()");
        // hide element by id
        webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                "document.getElementById('your_id').style.display='none';})()");

    }
    });

webview.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: It should be `"javascript:(function() {document.getElementById('your_id').style.display='none';})()"` (without `[0]`)

Comment: I'm using the same code but it does not having any effect on webView

Comment: same here. I cannot even get alert('helllo'); to work. And I have set js enabled to true.

Comment: It is working in onPageFinished(). Is there any chance to hide the div while loading itself?
Thanks in advance

Comment: @SandeepReddyM why not hide the webview and when till onPageFinish called visible the webview. WebView will show exactly how you want to show to user.

Comment: But it's taking time to hide the element.Is there any solution to avoid delay while executing the javascript?

Answer (score 9):

I got it!
By injecting javascript I had to use

> webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function()
>   { " +
>                       "document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].style.display
>   = 'none'; " +
>                       "})()");

That removes the link ( code). Replacing ('a') with ('img') would remove the images.

(thanks [lexanderA - Injecting JavaScript into a WebView](http://lexandera.com/2009/01/injecting-javascript-into-a-webview/) )

Answer (score 1):

I use [WebViewSuite](https://github.com/siralam/WebViewSuite)

and implement this

```
webViewSuite = findViewById(R.id.webViewSuite);
webViewSuite.startLoading("https://example.com/blog/");
```

and added customizeClient to WebViewSuite

```
webViewSuite.customizeClient(new WebViewSuite.WebViewSuiteCallback() {
      @Override
      public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
      }

      @Override
      public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        hideSomeSectionOfBlog(view);
      }

      @Override
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return false;
      }
    });
```

and use function to hide elements

```
 private void hideSomeSectionOfBlog(WebView view) {
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
      "document.getElementById('Top_bar').style.display='none';" +
      "document.getElementById('Filters').style.display='none';" +
      "document.getElementById('Footer').style.display='none';" +
      "document.getElementsByClassName('Header').style.display='none';" +
      "})()");
  }
```

Hope to be useful

***Note:*** if id not exist JavaScript get error.

example if Filters do not exists id ,Footer and Header do not display='none'
If you do not trust Separate like this

```
view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
      "document.getElementById('Footer').style.display='none';})()");
view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
      "document.getElementById('Header').style.display='none';})()");
```