# In a WebView, how can I block notifications from a website that says "Download our mobile app"?

Tags: android

When I click on the link, the Facebook website has a notification at the top that say "Download our app". I want to be able to remove that. Here is my WebView Activity:

```
public class FacebookActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

WebView webView;
String url = "https://www.facebook.com";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_facebook);

    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.facebookWebView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

}
```

Also I am just starting to learn Android development so if you see any mistakes, or easier ways to do this, that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by making a custom `WebViewClient` (basically a class that extends `WebViewClient` and can override its methods). The method you want to override is `onPageFinished()`. You can then inject custom js inside this method call on the page to do what you wish to the content.

these links should help:

https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/managing-webview#programmatic-actions

This SO question is similar:

[Any way to hide elements from webview? (android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029926/any-way-to-hide-elements-from-webview-android)

and this reddit post might help too:

https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/16yqhm/remove_html_elements_from_an_android_webview/

As mentioned in the above posts: make sure you get your html/js code right. A semicolon miss here or there wont lead to the effect you are expecting.