# Remove download option from Webview when playing a video android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, android-webview

I am trying to develop an android application that fetches a video URL from database and play it on he Webview as it provides a stable output unlike Videoview as it sometimes throws he Cant play video exception on a perfectly working video and internet connection.

The problem is I don't want the user to be able to download the video.

I used the below code to load the video and make it full-screen .

```
surfaceView.setWebChromeClient(new ChromeClient());
surfaceView.getSettings().setLightTouchEnabled(true);
surfaceView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
surfaceView.setSoundEffectsEnabled(true);
surfaceView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);
surfaceView.loadUrl(Videos.get(0).getVideo_Path());
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029926/any-way-to-hide-elements-from-webview-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029926/any-way-to-hide-elements-from-webview-android)

Comment: @Fecid Sorry but no,  I am looking to disable he download option available when loading a video.What you are referring me to is about hiding elements of a web page from the user's view.